# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '*'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session, exception

I'm trying to create session, using the following code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=THIRD-I;Initial Catalog=sessionlogin;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select (*) From logintable Where username='" + UserName.Text + "' and password='" + Password.Text + "'",conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()== "1")
{
    Session["user"] = UserName.Text;
    Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Its showing exception at `sda.Fill(dt);`

Comment: Take the parentheses out from around the *.

Answer (score 0):

You need count of records from the data adapter. So the SQL query should be `new SqlDataAdapter("Select count(*) From logintable Where username='" + UserName.Text + "' and password='" + Password.Text + "'",conn);`

Comment: I have written the query as above. now its saying **The resource cannot be found.**

Answer (score 0):

**To fix an error:**

Remove brackets from `Select (*)` or if you looking for total number add `count`

Must be `select *` or `select count(*)`

But your full code required big refactoring.

1. Disposing objects
2. Parameterize query
3. Assuming you take user input you should filter input

Comment: I have written the query as `select count(*)`. now its saying **The resource cannot be found**